# What are the dynamics of the "break the surface tension with a drop of soap" experiment?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, surface-tension, viscosity

There's a common experiment exemplified in the first few seconds of this video:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WsksFbFZeeU

You put some food coloring in the center of a plate of milk, then put a drop of soap in the center of the plate, and the food coloring shoots off to the sides of the plate.

The soap lowers the surface tension, so the parts of the surface where the soap has not reached have higher surface tension. A bit of surface straddling the transition region feels a net force towards the part where soap has not reached, and this causes the spread of the food coloring.

How thick is the layer of fluid that is accelerated in this manner? It appears to be a much slower process than the bursting of a bubble, so I assume the layer is considerably thicker than a bubble.

From dimensional analysis, I can guess the thickness is

$$t \approx \frac{\nu^2}{\sigma \rho}$$

with $\nu$ the dynamic viscosity, $\sigma$ the surface tension, and $\rho$ the density. Is that right, and where does it comes from?

If the surface of the milk is moving outward radially, somewhere else there must be fluid moving inward radially. Where does that occur and why? How fast does the interface between soapy and non-soapy milk move?

Comment: While i can't give you an answer directly this effect is known as the [Marangoni effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marangoni_effect). It describes mass transport due to a gradient in surface tension. Perhaps this gives you a direction to search for more info.